# SAP Spartacus - Sparta-Theme requesting Open Sans by default - not DSGVO compliant

Tags: spartacus-storefront

since January 2022 there is a court decision in germany which states that using Google Fonts over their web api is no longer data protection compliant.


Spartacus requests the Open Sans font initially by default. The font url is defined in the /_variables.scss of the sparta theme.


Unfortunately I wasn´t able to find a way to overwrite this variable or prevent the storefront from requesting the font in any way.


There should be any option to not load this font initially. Not only because this is an DSGVO topic but also to get rid of unnecessary requests at initial load.


Does anyone have an idea how to solve this or is there any recommendation from the Spartacus Team?

Comment: Ticket is already in progress.

Follow up: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/15534

Comment: as he mentioned above, the ticket was in progress and has been merged. The bug was that in some feature libraries, we were re-provisioning the global stylesheet. It will be backported to 4.3.2 and 3.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

With that said above in the comments section,

you have 3 options:

1 - wait for the backport to the maintenance branch(es), and upgrade accordingly

2 - create your own custom package from the Spartacus source code, and update the libraries that imports the entire `@import '~@spartacus/styles/scss/app';`. You can can change it to the same one found in this [pull request](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/15619/files)

3 - NOT ideal, but in your shell app, you can remove the stylesheets that causes those problems from the `"styles"` array property in `angular.json`, and/or remove the import to the styles on the respective package, and copy the styles from source to the stylesheet themselves.

The affected libraries are cart, order, and epd-visualization.